# React-i8next infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, i18next

I am using react i8next and using it to translate from English to arabic with react large app
in our app we have a module we created and it is called authnection module and it has it is own ui and it is own translation.json files

I have created a custom hook that takes every separate module i8next config , and init the i8next inside this custom hook
the problem that when user click on button to change language the app goes inside infinite loop and language not changed till I make refresh

my basic i8next config

```
    import i18next from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend';

const config = {
  supportedLngs: ['en', 'ar'],
  fallbackLng: "en",

  detection: {
    order: ['subdomain', 'path', 'cookie', 'htmlTag'],
    caches: ['cookie'],
  },
  resources: {

  },

  react: { useSuspense: true },

}
function init(config: any) {
  i18next
    .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .init(config)
  console.log("inited")
  return i18next;
}

i18next
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .init(config)


export default i18next;
```

my-custom hook code

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import i18next from "../config/translate"
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next"




export const useTranslator = (resources?: any) => {
    // @ts-ignore(resources)
    i18next.init(resources)
    // i18next.createInstance(resources)
    const { t, } = useTranslation()
    const [currentLang, setCurrentLang] = useState(i18next.language)

    useEffect(() => {
        document.body.dir = i18next.dir(currentLang)
        console.log(i18next);
        // setCurrentLang(i18next.language)
    }, [currentLang])

    return {
        t,
        currentLang,
        i18next

        // lang, setLang, url, changeLanguage, t
    }
}
```

the component that uses the custom hook and add it is own config

```
 const resources = {
        en: {
            translation: enTrans
        },
        ar: {
            translation: arTrans
        }

    }
    const config = {
        supportedLngs: ['en', 'ar'],
        resources,
        fallbackLng: "en",
        detection: {
            order: ['subdomain', 'path', 'cookie', 'htmlTag'],
            caches: ['cookie'],
        },

        react: { useSuspense: true },

    }
    const { t } = useTranslator(config)
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("renderdcx");
    }, [])
    return (
        <>
            <h1> Errors : {error} </h1>
            <h1> {t("login.name")}: {displayName}</h1>
            <h1> {t("login.email")}: {email} </h1>
           </>
)
```